# The quotient of two recursive sequences

Tags: number-theory

I am working with the following recursive sequences.

$a_{n+1}=3a_{n}+4b_{n}$, $b_{n+1}=2a_{n}+3b_{n}$ ; $a_{0}=3,b_{0}=2$.

By the way, these sequences came from the solutions for the Pells equation $a^2-db^2=1$.

We can use the solutions to Pell's equation to approximate $\sqrt{2}$ by taking the quotient of $\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}$, and it can be shown that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=\sqrt{2}$. One question that I have is how to attempt finding a closed form for the recursive sequences found by the quotient $\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}$?

Thank you.

Comment: With $x_n=a_n / b_n$ the recursion is $x_{n+1}=(3x_n+4)/(2x_n+3)$. The closed form is [not too pretty](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x(n%2B1)%3D(3x(n)%2B4)%2F(2x(n)%2B3)).

Comment: That's essentially the closed form that comes from considering $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ separately.

Comment: @GregMartin Right, but to consider $a_n, b_n$ separately one would presumably have to first calculate $$\left( \begin{matrix} 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 \end{matrix} \right)^n$$
which is essentially just as *un*-pretty.